# Google Maps API and Fusion Tables query with CONTAINS

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to get the following Google Maps JS API v3.7 Fusion Tables query to work. I have not had success. I keep getting more locations than I should; the ones with location data (currently two locations). The only location I should be getting back is "Rockefeller Chapel". It's as if the API is totally ignoring the query.

```js
this.buildingsLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(3418043);
this.buildingsLayer.setQuery("SELECT LatLng FROM 3418043 WHERE PropertyName CONTAINS 'Rockefeller'");
this.buildingsLayer.setMap(this.map);
```

Can anyone help me to see what the heck I'm doing wrong? Can anyone get it to work?

The Fusion Table is here:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=19HYOu84Oi8Id-dskNyRZxVAjE01CLm8cfNg8dAI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'LatLng',
    from: '3418043',
    where: "PropertyName CONTAINS 'Rockefeller'"
  }
});
layer.setMap(map);
```

[Code from here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)

See full page here
http://jsfiddle.net/99jVg/